# Conformal map between $\mathbb{C}\setminus((-\infty, -1]\cup[1,\infty))$ and $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid 0 < \operatorname{Im}(z) < 7\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

As it says in the title, I am looking for a conformal map from $\mathbb{C}\setminus((-\infty, -1]\cup[1,\infty))$ to $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid 0 < \operatorname{Im}(z) < 7\}$, but with the following restriction on the boundary components: $(-\infty, -1]$ is mapped to $\operatorname{Im}(z) = 7$ and $[1, \infty)$ is mapped to $\operatorname{Im}(z) = 0$.

So far I have been able to map $\mathbb{C}\setminus((-\infty, -1]\cup[1,\infty))$ to $\{w \in \mathbb{C} \mid 0 < \operatorname{Im}(w) < 7\}$, but I don't know if the boundary components are mapped to their counterparts in the desired way. I used the following sequence of maps (note, the branch of the logarithm is always the one with argument $(0, 2\pi)$):

> - $z \mapsto\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{z - 1}$ maps $\mathbb{C}\setminus((-\infty, -1]\cup[1,\infty))$ to $\mathbb{H}\setminus\{bi \mid b \in [1, \infty)\}$.
> - $z \mapsto \dfrac{z-i}{z+i}$ maps $\mathbb{H}\setminus\{bi \mid b \in [1, \infty)\}$ to $\mathbb{D}\setminus[0, 1)$.
> - $z \mapsto \sqrt{z}$ maps $\mathbb{D}\setminus[0, 1)$ to the upper half disc.
> - $z \mapsto z + \frac{1}{z}$ maps the upper half disc to the lower half plane.
> - $z \mapsto \log z$ maps the lower half plane to $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \pi < \operatorname{Im}(z) < 2\pi\}$.
> - $z \mapsto \frac{7}{\pi}(z - \pi i)$ maps $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \pi < \operatorname{Im}(z) < 2\pi\}$ to $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid 0 < \operatorname{Im}(z) < 7\}$.

The after applying the first and second map, $(-\infty, -1]$ is mapped to $[0, 1)$. What happens to this boundary component under the third map? It seems like it should remain unchanged, but geometrically it seems that it should be mapped to $(-1, 1)$.

Is there an alternative approach to this problem which would make it easier to see what happens to the boundary components?

Note, if we could construct a map as desired, except it swapped the boundary components, we could define a new map by (post)composing with the map $z \mapsto 7 - z$; this new map would then have all the desired properties.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you care? :)

Comment: @AlexYoucis: It is a past comprehensive exam question.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "where $(0,1)$ maps under the third map": the map you've written down doesn't extend continuously to the boundary (and won't in general unless your conformal maps are [between domains bounded by Jordan curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory's_theorem_(conformal_mapping))). The inverse image of your third conformal map extends continuously to the boundary; it will not be injective. So what you want to do is figure out what points have inverse image in $[0,1)$, and say  that's what it maps to. This is what you call 'geometrically'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sine function maps the strip $\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |\operatorname{Re}(z)|<\tfrac{\pi}{2}\}$ biholomorphically onto $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid |x|\geq 1\}$. So start with $z\mapsto\arcsin(z)$ and compose with a suitable linear transformation.

Answer (score 3):

As Mike Miller said, boundary slits should be thought of as "two-sided curves", and conformal maps are apt to split the two sides: formally, they may have different boundary limits depending on the direction of approach to the same boundary point. The simplest example of $z\mapsto \sqrt{z}$ mapping $\mathbb C\setminus (-\infty,0]$ onto half-plane: two sides of the negative semi-axis go in two different places.

For your problem, I  would start with 
$$z\mapsto \frac{1+z}{1-z}$$
which transforms the domain into $\mathbb C\setminus (-\infty,0]$. The two boundary pieces are separated by point $-1$ (it came from $\infty$, which separated them in the original domain).

Then square root onto right halfplane; the two pieces are separated by $\pm i$: one is between $\pm i$ and one is outside. Use a fractional linear transformation to send them to $0$ and $\infty$: 
$$z\mapsto \frac{z+i}{z-i}$$ 
This was a preparation for applying the logarithm. The logarithm breaks the boundary of halfplane at $0$, sending two parts onto two sides of infinite strip. Now only cosmetics remain: moving the strip where you want it to be.