# Does a conformal map take boundaries to boundaries?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I think it is a well-known result that conformal maps between sets in $\mathbb{C}$ take boundaries to boundaries.  However, I looked around a little and I had trouble finding this result.  Is it true?  Also, is there a quick proof of it?

I apologize if this has already been asked.

Comment: In some sense, yes, but you need to be careful. A conformal map from a domain extends continuously to the boundary if the boundary is a Jordan curve. But if your open set is, say, the unit disc minus the nonnegative real axis, there's no continuous extension. There was an old question about this with a good answer, let me try to find it.

Comment: Thank you.  And when there is a continuous extension, this preserves boundaries, correct?

Comment: With some minor assumptions (compactness of the closure, say), yes. I can write a proof in a minute.

Comment: This seems to be harder than I remembered. For simply connected Jordan domains what you want is [Carathéodory's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_%28conformal_mapping%29). For some discussion on the case I mentioned in my first comment see my comment and the first bit of Behaviour's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/900725/98602). I believe it to be true that a conformal map between bounded Jordan domains (no requirement of simple connectivity) extends to a homeomorphism of the closure, but I do not have a proof.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "take boundaries to boundaries".  Presumably, it's a statement involving some limits; make it precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that a conformal map $f: \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$ extends continuously to $\bar f: \overline{\Omega}_1 \to \overline{\Omega}_2$, it is true that $\bar f(\partial \Omega_1) \subset \partial \Omega_2$. For pick a sequence of points $(z_i)$ converging to $z$ in the boundary; then $\bar f(z) = \lim f(z_i)$. Call $\lim f(z_i) = z'$, and suppose $z' \in \Omega_2$ itself. Since $f$ is a homeomorphism, let $g = f^{-1}$. Because $g$ is continuous, $g(z') = \lim g(f(z_i)) = \lim z_i$; but the former is in $\Omega_1$, so $\lim z_i \in \Omega_1$, contradictory to our assumption.

It is not a given that a conformal map should extend continuously to the boundary. For instance, the Riemannm map taking $\Omega = D^2 \setminus \Bbb R_{\geq 0}$ to the open unit disc doesn't have a continuous extention to its boundary. (The inverse map taking $D^2$ conformally to $\Omega$ does, though. It maps two points to each element of the strip.) [Carathéodory's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(conformal_mapping)) says that the Riemann map from any (bounded) Jordan domain to the unit disc extends continuously to the boundary (inducing a homeomorphism). I suspect a similar theorem is true for multiply connected Jordan domains, but I don't have a proof.

Comment: Is it true that a conformal equivalence $\Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$ extends continuously to $\overline{\Omega}_1$ (though not to a homeomorphism) if $\Omega_1$ is a Jordan domain but $\Omega_2$ is not?