# Comformal map in hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^n$, $n\geq 3$.

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I'm working with some result in Do carmo, Riemannian Geometry. Which consits in to  find all isometries in $\mathbb{H}^n$, but in the case $\mathbb{H}^n$, $n \geq 3$, the autor said the comformal map $h$ maps $\partial \mathbb{H}^n$ to $\partial \mathbb{H}^n$. In a first place I think that statement  was due some special property of comformal maps. But I find this

[Does a conformal map take boundaries to boundaries?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086972/does-a-conformal-map-take-boundaries-to-boundaries)

So, I don't know how prove this affirmation. Some hint?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by conformal in your question? What dimension? Do you assume connected domain?....

Comment: @Moishe Kohan. Comformal map, means the map  which preserve angles, the domain in this case is $\mathbb{R}^n$ , just that $h$ maps $\mathbb{H}^n$ to $\mathbb{H}^n$. The dimension is $n\geq 3$.

Comment: No, your domain cannot be $R^n$, it should be the 1-point compactification of $^n$. Then all conformal transformations are diffeomorphisms (actually, Moebius transformations), hence, map boundaries of subsets of $R^n\cup\infty$ to boundaries of the images.